# Background problems IE7 v7.0 vs IE7 v8.0 FACEBOOK bug (see answer)

Tags: css, background, internet-explorer-7

Im working with a cross-browser compatibility, fixed everything fixable for IE7 and IE8. But it seems there is a slight (huge) problem with the background which is called by CMS. 
As far as it seems, there is no problem in IE7 v8.0 BUT in IE7 v7.0 looks moved to the side in most pages, but not in others.
I figured it was because of a fix i did for some lost positions, but when i searched for a lost object in the right there was none.
And i have no idea how to make this bg to look right.

Please help me! im going crazy with this!
Page:
http://www.tvazteca.com/homes/laislaelreality

I think the problem its the background position. I cant make it work for the IE7.

```
<body class="fondo-pagina" data-twttr-rendered="true">

<style type="text/css">
    .fondo-pagina {background:url(http://static.tvazteca.com/imagenes/2012/29/1634805.jpg)  no-repeat; background-position: 50% 40px;background-color:#0b4a51; 
    *background-position: 50% 0 !important;
     }
        .bgBottom{background:url() bottom center no-repeat;}
</style>
```

The style up there is added automatically by the CMS. Although i have the same class in the style sheet:

```
.fondo-pagina{
background: url(../img/fondoislaEtapa1.jpg) top center no-repeat;background-color: #0b4a51;
*overflow-x:hidden;background-position: 50% 0px!important;
*background-position: 50% 0px!important; }
```

I havent been able to make it work. I know im using hacks, and its not the best option, but i was asked to only use one style sheet for the site, so another one for IE7-IE8 was out of the question.

How can i make IE7 to read the background position? Is it going crazy because of the double clases?

Using Chrome and FF, element inspectors i found out none of the background position clases were taken for IE.

TY for reading :)

Comment: Please post the relative codes of the lost images, just a note - on IE 7 there is a horizontal scrollbar

Comment: You mean, the bad positions i fixed? I thought that was what was causing the x-scrollbar. But selecting everything shows nothing floating there. Im thinking its the 'background-position: 50% 0px!important;' css class that its being ignored and the why its making that horizontal scroll bar. But its making me go crazy why it works on IE7 version8.0 and not on IE7 version7.0

Comment: Please post the codes related (CSS, html and JS) to your issue. It's hard for people to go through your site. Be as simple as you can and focus on one part of the issue

Comment: Sorry, i didnt know what was the problem thats why at the beginning i didn't add the code. I had no idea if it was some image, div or anything doing it. Now i think its the background-position. I edited my post with the code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.
Nothing was wrong with the Html php and my Css
The problem comes from FACEBOOK:

```
<script>
!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id))      {js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");
</script>
```

The scrip has to be placed in the div that contains the likes/comments etc. Other way it will go crazy in IE.
It opens up a big div that forces the page to be contained and makes horizontal scrollbar to be extended. As result, the background will take such width as the base one and position itself on the 50% 0px of that thing.

It only affects IE versions. The other browsers work fine.